# Rewrite db.example.com to example.com/db

Tags: apache

I've got myself an apache server and I'm trying to learn it's quirks...
I've got DNS to point example.com to 1.2.3.4 and I've set up a vhost on the apache2 server.

Now I want to, in the same vhost, point db.example.com to serv the contents of example.com/db.
I was hoping I could use some kind of mod_rewrite og ServerAlias, but sofar I've hot a wall.

The DNS part is covered, I just can't figure out what to do in apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.htaccess` file, try something among the lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^db\.example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/db/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that NEARLY solved my problem.and
Is there any way to point http ://db.example.com to http ://example.com/db and https ://db.example.com to https ://example.com/db ?

Both https and http points to the same sitecontent.

Comment: try adding RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on as one of the conditions for http and try RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on for SSL;

Comment: I tried with this:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^db\.v42\.dk
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) http://v42.dk/db/$1 [L]
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^db\.v42\.dk
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) https://v42.dk/db/$1 [L]`

But couldn't get it to work.